While loading a tensorflow model getting error as "Unable to synchronously open object (object 'sequential_3' doesn't exist)"
tensorflow==2.16.1
keras=3.x.x
python>=3.9

tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
Can anyone please help me here!!!
